# Hotspot как прослушивать wifi соединения

Tags: c++, python, node.js

Есть Unifi APs которые в свою очередь обращаются к Unifi Controller в котором есть Guest portal, но в связи с большой нагрузкой, Unifi Controller не успевает обрабатывать соединения и выдавать интернет пользователям. (сервера мощные)

Задача: Написать сервис на шлюзе, который в свою очередь будет проверять кто подключился, лезть в базу и проверять оставшейся время.

Вопрос: В какую сторону копать? как и с помощью чего можно отловить момент подключения к wifi и слушать запросы? Возможно используемые языки: C++/NodeJS/Python/Ruby

Comment: Вы вместо решения проблем с производительностью хотите все переписать? Странно это. Лучше разберитесь, отчего контроллер тормозит.

Comment: Controller слишком громоздкий, пишет много логов, статистики, записывает и дублирует каждого гостя, а мне все что надо это получить ip проверить, дать интернет.

Comment: а пользователей у вас сколько?
Вы можете просто выбросить Gust Portal от UNIFY и прицепить любой другой, тот же SQUID.

Comment: Постоянный онлайн более 7тыс человек, про squid спасибо, сейчас почитаю